# Azure B2C with Native Client - MsalClientException: The server has not found anything matching the requested URI

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-b2c

Trying to run a basic Azure AD B2C authentication from a Native App. I followed the [WPF App registration guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-wpf-desktop-app), and am using extract from the code provided in the [Git Hub example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop/blob/msalv3/active-directory-b2c-wpf/App.xaml.cs).

Using the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` SDK, when I run `await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.ApiScopes).ExecuteAsync();`, I get the following exception:

> **Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException:** 'The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).'

I run this from an test with NUnit.net

I did the following tries and checks:

- Tried the recommended URI: `https://mytenanturl.com.b2clogin.com/oauth2/nativeclient`
- Tried a custom URI such as `https://mytenanturl.com/test/auth/nativeclient`
- Tried a custom URI such as `uri://mytenanturl.com/test/auth/nativeclient`
- Tried one of the 3 URIs pre-registered by default on Azure: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`
- Tried with a local URI such as `https://127.0.0.1/dev/`
- These URIs are all registered on the Azure `Portal / App Registration / Authentication`, with `Platform Configuration` set to `Mobile and desktop applications`
- In the App Regsitration Manifest, it says

  "replyUrlsWithType": [
  {
  "url": "https://127.0.0.1/dev",
  "type": "InstalledClient"
  },
  {
  "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient",
  "type": "InstalledClient"
  }, etc,
- When I inspect the `IPublicClientApplication` object, I can see the URI correctly inclued within `.AppConfig.RedirectUri`. However, `PublicClientApplication.RedirectUri` says it is Null. I am confused beause I cannot even understand where this property is comming from, since it does not appear in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet), where `PublicClientApplication Class` or its parent classes have no `RedirectUri` property.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [sample provided in the Ms Documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop/blob/msalv3/active-directory-b2c-wpf/App.xaml.cs) shows the client builder invoking `.WithB2CAuthority(AuthoritySignUpSignIn)`, which is not correct.

The QuickStart blade in the Azure AD App Registration page shows to use `WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)` where `Tenant` can be `companyurl.com` or the `Directory (tenant) Id` provided on the overview page of the App Registration.